# How to permanently delete segments in oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespace

In the **segment advisor recommendations** in oracle's enterprise manager (where you click on **recommendation details per tablepsace**), I seem to be seeing indexes/partitions/tables and schema names of objects which I already deleted/dropped prior to looking at the segment advisor recommendations.

How do I permanently delete those objects? (No I do not want to shrink/reorganize/compress these objects, I want to permanently delete them and free up some space on my tablespaces)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll try this when I get back to work a bit later, thanks man

Comment: @Ivan It didn't work, those indexes/tables/schema are still there, I tried dropping them but it says that those objects does not exist

Comment: There is also a global (database wise) command `PURGE DBARECYCLEBIN`

Comment: I tried that too and its PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN and it didn't work too. I used a sysdba user btw :/

Comment: Ok how do segment names do look like? Purge command drops segments belonging to dropped tables(indexes). Is this you case? Do not use any kind of adviser, simply query the view `DBA_SEGMENTS`.

Comment: okay, so I checked DBA_SEGMENTS using this query, SELECT SEGMENT_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME, BYTES,round((bytes)/1024/1024,2) mb_bytes
FROM DBA_SEGMENTS 
WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'USERS' AND SEGMENT_NAME = 'MY_GHOST_TABLE/INDEX'
ORDER BY bytes desc, SEGMENT_NAME; I didn't find anything, but when I removed the segment name on my where clause and compared the total bytes consumed, it was equal to the currently consumed space on my users tablespace. I went back to the adviser and tried to compress/shrink the ghost segments and ofourse, I was told that the objects does not exist.

Comment: why are these segments still in the advisor if these segments no longer exists?